# Intent making app reset when starting an a activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass a class to another activity via an intent, and something fails before the activity is created.

Here is the call in the main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigateChartActivity.class);
    TreeNode selectedOption = chart.getChild(position);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putParcelable("Selected", selectedOption);
    intent.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(intent);
```

And here is the other class, maybe I implemented something wrong in the Parcelable part:

```
public class TreeNode implements Parcelable {

String data = "";
TreeNode parent = null;
List<TreeNode> children;
String question = "";

public TreeNode(String data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    this.question = "";
}

public TreeNode(String data, String q) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    this.question = q;
}

public TreeNode() {

}


public TreeNode(Parcel parcel) {
    data = parcel.readString();
    parent = parcel.readTypedObject(TreeNode.CREATOR);
    parcel.readTypedList(children, TreeNode.CREATOR);
    question = parcel.readString();

}


public TreeNode addChild(TreeNode child) {
    child.parent = this;
    this.children.add(child);
    return child;
}



public void addMultipleChilds(TreeNode[] childs){
    for(int i = 0; i < childs.length;i++){
        addChild(childs[i]);
    }
}

public TreeNode getChild(int i){
    return this.children.get(i);
}

public String[] getListOfData(){
    String[] options = new String[this.children.size()];
    for(int i = 0;i<this.children.size();i++){
        options[i] = this.getChild(i).data.toString();
    }
    return options;
}



// Parcelable implementation

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override

public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(data);
    parcel.writeTypedObject(parent, i);
    parcel.writeTypedList(children);
    parcel.writeString(question);
}

public static Creator<TreeNode> CREATOR = new Creator<TreeNode>() {
    public TreeNode createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new TreeNode(parcel);
    }

    public TreeNode[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TreeNode[size];
    }
};
```

The FinalNode class is also Parcelable, with the same implementation, I will post it in case it's necessary

Thank you for any help

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes I'm trying to get them, but they reset when the app restarts itself

Comment: @YasmaniLlanes seems like I'm having stacks of > 8MB and it gives me stackOverflow, this is the message I'm having: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android, PID 9933     java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB